# Filter values in the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to filter `products` depending of the selected `category` which can be selected with a drop-down menu. `products` belongTo `category`

[image: Screenshot of the application.]

- *What do I have to change in the controller to filter `products` depending of the chosen value of the drop-down menu?*
- *How can I add an empty field in the drop-down menu and display all products when it is chosen?*

Here is the current Ember CLI code:

**app/routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      categories: this.store.find('category'),
      products: this.store.find('product')
    };
  }
});
```

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCategory: null,

  categories: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.categories');
    return model;
  },

  products: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.products');
    return model;
  }.property('selectedCategory')
});
```

**app/templates/index.hbs**

```
<p>
{{view "select"
       content=model.categories
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       value=selectedCategory
       }}
</p>

{{#each product in products}}
  <li>{{product.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

**app/models/product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true }),
});
```

**app/models/category.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product', { async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do I have to change in the controller to filter products
>   depending of the chosen value of the drop-down menu?

You could create a computed property that filters the products like:

```
filteredProducts: function() {
    var selectedCategory = this.get('selectedCategory');
    var products = this.get('products');
    return products.filter(function(product) {
        return product.get('category.name') === selectedCategory;
    });
}.property('selectedCategory')
```

> How can I add an empty field in the drop-down menu and display all
>   products when it is chosen?

Just add `prompt` value in the Ember select view:

```
{{view "select" prompt="All products"
                content=categories
                optionLabelPath="content.name"
                optionValuePath="content.name"
                value=selectedCategory}}
```

And then when you observe the `selectedCategory`, if the user select's the prompt, the value of the selection will be `null`.

Thus you can update the `filteredProducts` computed property to take that into account as well:

```
filteredProducts: function() {
    var selectedCategory = this.get('selectedCategory');
    var products = this.get('products');
    if(selectedCategory) { // return filtered products
        return products.filter(function(product) {
            return product.get('category.name') === selectedCategory;
        });
    }
    return products;       // return all products
}.property('selectedCategory')
```